# How to make property overrides of C# classes during runtime

Tags: c#, oop, data-modeling

Consider some C# classes representing some application data. For instance `class A` with some properties:

```
public class A
{
    public bool P1 { set; get; }
    public string P2 { set; get; }
    public int P3 { set; get; }
}
```

Further I have different time ranges in my application. Lets say time range 1 and 2. At first my application is set for time range 1. Some instances of `A` exist in all time ranges alike. Now I switch to time range 2 and set a new value for `P2` of some instance of `A`. The new value should only effect time range 2. Upon switching back to time range 1, `P2` should have the old value. Switching back to time range `2`, `P2` is the new value again.

Whenever I set any value in my data model it should be specific to the current time range and not effect the others. On the other hand values that were not changed should be shared over all time ranges. There is no requirements whatsoever on how these time ranges should be represented. Might be some `TimeRange` class, but might as well be something else.

How would you design such a scenario in C#?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "mode 1" and "mode 2" - the scope of that change, for one thing. If you could give more context I suspect people would find it easier to answer the question.

Comment: I added some extra information and replaced "mode" with "time range". Do you think it's sufficiently easy to understand now?

Comment: Not really, because we still don't know much about what you mean by "time range". How is this communicated to different objects, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must replace property to method, because it realted with time range. Or include time range to this class if it possible.

Comment: Possible signature of methods public string GetP2(timeRange); public string SetP2(string p2, timerange);

Comment: Good idea. But that is not an option, since I want to leave open the possibility to use the Entity Framework. Therefore it must be properties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change `string` P2 with `Tuple<string, string>` so you can access both values switching your "mode".